# Are these main files to refer for semantic ui to work properly?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, semantic-ui

```
semantic.css
semantic.min.css
semantic.min.js
```

Are these files sufficient for semantic-ui to work properly?

Comment: You don’t need **both** `semantic.css` and `semantic.min.css` — You just need 1, and I’d pick `semantic.min.css`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yes, you can also check https://www.jsdelivr.com/projects/semantic-ui for all the main and component files

Answer (score 0):

First of all, `semantic.css` and `semantic.min.css` are both functionaly the same but the `.min` one has all unnecessary characters removed in order to make the file size smaller.

Anyway, You need those two files (`.js` - `.css`) minimized or not **BUT** you also need [JQuery](https://jquery.com/) library